# Hamilton path and Euler circuits in Cycle graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

Can $C_n$ has $2*n$ Euler circuits and $3*n$ Hamilton paths in the Cyclic graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bt $C_n$ you mean the cycle with $n$ vertices, right?

A cycle on $n$ vertices has $2n$ Euler circuits: Each circuit is uniquely determined by the starting vertex ($n$ choices) and then the direction (2 choices).

Each Hamiltonian path is also uniquely determined by the starting vertex $n$ choices and then the direction 2 choices. So there are $2n$ Hamiltonian paths.

Each Hamiltonian *cycle* is also uniquely determined by the starting vertex $n$ choices and then the direction 2 choices. So there are $2n$ Hamiltonian cycles.

So to answer your question in short, yes there are $2n$ Eulerian circuits, no there are only $2n$ Hamiltonian paths.

Comment: Thanks @mike for the explanation :)